# is it easy to do this [Camel-k; Hazelcast; XSLT]?

Tags: kubernetes, xslt, hazelcast, apache-camel-k

I want create a cluster kube with Camel-k and Hazelcast nodes.
The goal is someone call a WebService via an ApiGateway outside Cluster, the call is routing in my serviceKubeCamel_k ; this message is transforming by some XSLT and return the response.

i would like the all XSLT are loaded on Hazelcast Map (Key:xxx  value:"xsl:stelsheet........")
into my route camel-k when i want transform input Exchange with XSLT-Saxon get from Hazelcast ..
is it possible ?

[image]
thks

i want create a cache in memory of all XSLT into Map Hazelcast;
it is loaded Manually or Every Hour from PersistentVolume by a other Camel-K job.

like that the loading of the xslt is not done via a disk reading of the persistent volume but of the hazelcast node in memory.

and why not use this technic to load WSDL and XSD for XML validation via a schema from the cache.

Comment: if you want to ask this in with an XSLT tag, it may be an idea to remove all the domain specific stuff that at least I have no clue about, is it possible to just invent a scenario with out any domain specific knowledge?

Comment: is it a bad idea to cache xsl? Do you think it's better to leave the xsl on a volume persistence and call it every time?

Answer (score 0):

I've used on many occasions a "in-memory-cache" of compiled XSLT stylesheets that were managed from some updatable datastore.  A background process would discover when the XSLT source was updated in whatever system was managing it (on disk, in a database, updated via an API call, etc) and would then refresh the cache of compiled XSLT stylesheets.  This is quite doable at least using Saxon/Saxonica.

Comment: how do you do use camel-k for use xml inline to transform with memorycache xslt ?

Comment: I was answering w.r.t. XSLT.  I'm afraid that the specifics of caching within camel-k will have to be for someone else.  Good luck with it.